# Reset DropDown Value to Default(Select) when a particular value is selected

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery, razor

Cshtml Code

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group xenon_form">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Billing</label>
        @{ Html.EnableClientValidation(false); }
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.patientProviderDetails.BillingProviderId,
            new SelectList(ViewBag.BillingProviderDetails, "PhysicianId", "DisplayName"),
            "Select",
            new { @class = "coustomize_select BillingProvider_Name" })
        @{ Html.EnableClientValidation(true); }
    </div>
</div>
```

Now we select in dropdown value **Add_New** from this and we see our modal and save data by calling API.
Now I want to reset it back to '**Select**'

I tried this but only selected option change in the background- but Add View is still visible to the user-

**$(".BillingProvider_Name option:first").attr('selected', 'selected');**

```
<div class="SumoSelect sumo_patientProviderDetails.BillingProviderId" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-expanded="true">
<select class="coustomize_select BillingProvider_Name SumoUnder" id="patientProviderDetails_BillingProviderId" name="patientProviderDetails.BillingProviderId" tabindex="-1">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
<option value="1">XENON HEALTH PC</option>
<option value="12">RADIUS ANESTHESIA</option>
<option value="Add_New">Add New</option></select>
<p class="CaptionCont SelectBox search" title=" Add New">
    <span> Add New</span><label><i></i></label>

<input type="text" class="search-txt" value="" placeholder="Search"></p><div class="optWrapper"><ul class="options"><li class="opt"><label>Select</label></li><li class="opt"><label>XENON HEALTH PC</label></li><li class="opt"><label>RADIUS ANESTHESIA</label>
</li><li class="opt selected"><label>Add New</label></li></ul><p class="no-match" style="display: none;">No matches for "<em></em>"</p></div></div>
```

Comment: Hi try like this `$('select.BillingProvider_Name').prop('selectedIndex', 0);` and see if that works